# filter google sheet based on cell value using a regex expression that match any numeric values and a specific string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Below is a code that filters spreadsheet based on specific column values and copy matches to a new spreadsheet

```
function filterkhaled(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
    var reg = /^\d+$/;
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    var newData = data.filter(row => ["yes"].includes(row[12]) | row.match(reg));
    newSheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
```

I want basically that filter matches the string "yes" or any numeric value, and then copy the corresponding matches into new spreadsheet. The code here `row.match(reg)`shows the following error **TypeError: row.match is not a function**
is there a way to make the regex filter work?

Here is how the starting table look like
[image: source sheet, where green marked rows are to be copied to a new spreadsheet based on the value of column M]

The output shall contain all green rows.

Comment: I thought that the reason for your error of `TypeError: row.match is not a function` is due to that `row` is an array. But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for this. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: I have provided a sample input, the filter criteria is the values of column M, if its any numeric value or 'yes' then it matches, and matches shall be copied to a new tab.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! Working. Nevertheless, I tried to combine the existing expressions with another boolean expression for a different column, namely column F, to ignore a specific value but it is not working. The code is `var newData = data.filter(row => row[5] !== "val uniq" && row[12] == "yes" || row[12].match(reg)); ` is there any suggestion why the first expression being ignored?

Comment: About your new question of `Nevertheless, I tried to combine the existing expressions with another boolean expression for a different column, namely column F, to ignore a specific value but it is not working. The code is var newData = data.filter(row => row[5] !== "val uniq" && row[12] == "yes" || row[12].match(reg));  is there any suggestion why the first expression being ignored?`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new question, for example, when you want to retrieve the values that the column "M" is `yes` or number AND the column "F" is not `val uniq`, how about `var newData = data.filter(row => row[5] !== "val uniq" && (row[12] == "yes" || row[12].match(reg)));`? But, if I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you so much for your response! Indeed you understood my question right. I have tried your suggestion and it works like charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike I am actually facing an erorr where the last row is not copied correctly.. I have edited the function further more, details below...

Comment: I would like to support you and your new question of `I am actually facing an erorr where the last row is not copied correctly.. I have edited the function further more, details below...`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: thanks for replying, I have used the function you provided me before and add one more function that copy the columns with the index [7, 13 ], then paste them into the  sheet in columns A and B and then delete all other columns. but this fail to copy the last row as in the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 3rd question of `I have used the function you provided me before and add one more function that copy the columns with the index [7, 13 ], then paste them into the sheet in columns A and B and then delete all other columns. but this fail to copy the last row as in the screenshot.`. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your 3rd question?

Comment: Hallo Tanaike, I have solved it, I just figured it out. Can I ask you about another topic ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Hallo Tanaike, I have solved it, I just figured it out. Can I ask you about another topic ?`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. So, in this case, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245493/discussion-between-khaled-ghazi-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that the reason for your error of `TypeError: row.match is not a function` is due to that `row` is an array.
- `["yes"].includes(row[12])` is the same with `row[12] == "yes"`.
- In this case, please use `||` instead of `|`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function filterkhaled() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
  var reg = /^\d+$/;
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newData = data.filter(row => row[12] == "yes" || row[12].match(reg));
  if (newData.length == 0) return;
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

- When this script is run, the rows that the value of column "M" is `yes` or the number are put to the new sheet.

#### References:

- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)